# Framer motion: how to set display to none after animation ends?

Tags: animation, display, framer-motion

So I have this component where it is supposed to be set to display none after the animation but i cant seem to find it in the docs nor find other questions regarding thjis.

I've temporary solved it by nesting it on another motion.div and animate the display with delay set to match the supposed outro (opacity to 0)

Edit: I've edited some part of the code here. But anyways this one is just a supposedly a temporary solution, I still want to know if there are more and better ways to do it.

```
    <motion.div
  initial={{display:'flex'}}
  animate={{display:'none'}}
  transition={{delay:3.3}}
  >
    <motion.div 
    initial={{opacity: 1}}
    animate={{opacity: 0,}}
    transition={{delay:3, duration: 0.3,}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`transitionEnd: { display: "none" }`

From this [weirdly-named section of the docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/###targetandtransition):

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug but even when i followed the docs it didn't work. In fact, it just ruined the whole animation instead. Now it doesn't even animate anymore if i set the display to none. but when i choose other values like flex, it is working

Comment: It seems to work in their CodeSandbox example. Can you post an example of what you're doing in CodeSandbox or CodePen?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `onAnimationComplete` prop with a state or ref that could hold the state of the animation:

```
const [completed, setCompleted] = useState<boolean>(false);
...
<motion.div initial={{opacity: 1}}
            animate={{
              opacity: 0,
              display: completed ? "flex" : "none"
            }}
            onAnimationComplete={() => setCompleted(true)}
            transition={{delay:3, duration: 0.3}}/>
```